# Intersection Observer wierd behaviour in production

Tags: javascript

1. I am building a landing page and added intersection observer to header section. As soon as header moves out of the viewport an sticky nav class is added to navigation.
2. This functionality work properly in my local server, when I push it to git, so it can be hosted on netlify the nav as an weird behavior, sticky nav class is applied as soon as the page loads.
3. If I reload the hosted site 2 or 3 times then it behaves as expecting, but like 70% of the time sticky nav is applied before header moves out of the viewport.
4. I have tested it like an hour. In my pc this functionality works perfectly fine. But only when I push it to production the sticky nav is applied as soon as page loads.

My hosted site on netlify [hosted netlify link](https://wonderful-albattani-5839f3.netlify.app/)

My sticky nav code

```js
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Sticky nav

const toggleStickyNav = function (entries) {
  const [entry] = entries;
  console.log(entry);
  if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
    nav.classList.add('nav--sticky');
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove('nav--sticky');
    // Remove active nav link class from all nav links, this function got nothing to do with sticky nav
    activateNavlink(null);
  }
};

const stickyNavOptions = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: `-${navHeight}px`,
};

const headerObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
  toggleStickyNav,
  stickyNavOptions
);

headerObserver.observe(header);
```

Link to github repo
[github link](https://github.com/manjeshrv95/mogo)

Comment: I added a breakpoint in your `!entry.isIntersecting` conditional and it's not called on every page load. This is most likely related to the `defer` attribute used on the script tag generated by webpack (which is handled differently when you are testing locally).

Comment: You were right, defer attribute in script tag was causing this issue, I navigated to my dist folder and manually removed script tag from my html head and placed it at the end of body and removed defer attribute.

Comment: Instead of manually editing the generated HTML file you can control the `defer` attribute using the `scriptLoading` config param of `html-webpack-plugin` as documented here https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options

Comment: exactly what I need, Thanks you so much...

Answer (score 1):

Your script does not execute on every page load because of the `defer` attribute on the `script` tag generated by Webpack. You can remove that by using the `scriptLoading` config param documented [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options).